# What is the name for a word that is both singular and plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a term for words that have identical singular and plural forms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45039/is-there-a-term-for-words-that-have-identical-singular-and-plural-forms)

Oddly enough for a computing tutor, I encounter the need for this term fairly often.

I'm of course referring to words like 'sheep' or 'fish', which can be either singular or plural depending on the context.